# SparkJava websocket not working

Tags: java, websocket, spark-java

SparkJava web sockets won't work. Whenever I attempt to connect to it with a websocket tester, at 'ws://localhost:4567/echo' it gets an error 'undefined' and never connects, nor do any of the sout's or printStackTrace get called.

```
@WebSocket
public class EchoWebSocket {
private static final Queue<Session> sessions = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

@OnWebSocketConnect
public void connected(Session session) {
    System.out.println("Client connected");

    //sessions.add(session);
}

@OnWebSocketClose
public void closed(Session session, int statusCode, String reason) {
    System.out.println("Client disconnected");

    //sessions.remove(session);
}

@OnWebSocketMessage
public void message(Session session, String message) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Got: ");// + message);   // Print message

    //session.getRemote().sendString(message); // and send it back
}

@OnWebSocketError
public void throwError(Throwable error) {
    error.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

how I call it

```
Spark.webSocket("/echo", new EchoWebSocket());
Spark.init();
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Are you sure you are using the code you provided here? It works without any problems on my machine.

Answer (score -1):

You need to define the class, not create an object.

```
Spark.webSocket("/echo", EchoWebSocket.class);
```

Comment: Passing the instance of the handler works too. Both options are acceptable.